# Method to extract exact 95% confidence values from stat_smooth(method = "glm")

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I have produced a glm interaction plot using ggplot2. I have attached the code I have used and the plot

[image: plot showing grey shaded 95% interval that i want to extract the values from] .

I know that the grey shaded areas represent the 95% condfidence interval, but I am wondering if there is a method to get the exact values of the grey shaded areas and therefore 95% confidence interval?

```
#bind data togther
```

`Modern_EarlyHolocene<-rbind(FladenF30, FladenB30, Early_Holocene)`

```
#Build modern vs Holocene model
```

`Modern_EarlyHolocene<-glm(Max_Height~Age+Time_period, data=Modern_EarlyHolocene,family = gaussian)`

```
#Produce gg interaction plot
```

`Modern_EarlyHolocene_plot<-ggplot(data=Modern_EarlyHolocene) +`
  `aes(x = Age, y = Max_Height, group = Time_period, color = Time_period,) +`>
  `geom_point( alpha = .7) +`
  `stat_smooth(method = "glm", level=0.95) +`
  `expand_limits(y=c(0,90), x=c(0,250)`)

`#add axis labels`

`Modern_EarlyHolocene_plot + labs(x = "Age (years)", y = 'Maximum height (mm)') +`
  `theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 14, colour = "Black"),`
        `legend.title=element_blank()) +`
 `theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),` 
        `axis.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can access de plot data with `layer_data(Modern_EarlyHolocene_plot, i)` with i corresponding to the layer to return, in the order added to the plot

Answer (score 0):

You are effectively fitting a different regression line for each Time_period, so your glm has to include an interaction term. It should be:

```
Modern_EarlyHolocene<-glm(Max_Height~Age*Time_period, data=Modern_EarlyHolocene)
```

I do not have your data, so see below for an example with iris:

```
fit = glm(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length * Species,data=iris)
g1 = ggplot(iris,aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width,color=Species)) +
geom_point( alpha = .7) + stat_smooth(method = "glm", level=0.95)
```

[image]

To get the se of the predictions, you do:

```
pred = predict(fit,iris,se.fit = TRUE)
df_pred = data.frame(iris,pred=pred$fit,se=pred$se)
```

We can plot this, and the upper and lower bounds of the prediction are 1.96 * the standard error:

```
g2 = ggplot(df_pred,aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width,color=Species)) +
geom_point( alpha = .7) + 
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=pred-1.96*se,ymax=pred+1.96*se,fill=Species),alpha=0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that was helpful! However I am asking if I can extract/list the exact values that it uses to make the confidence intervals?

Comment: when you do pred = predict(fit,iris,se.fit = TRUE), the standard error values are in pred$se. +/- 1.96 of this se is the upper and lower confidence interval. These are the exact values used in ggplot2 to make the confidence interval as I have shown in the example above

Comment: Ok i see! You cannot assign the fit object to the same name. do fit<-glm(Max_Height~Age*Time_period, data=Modern_EarlyHolocene)

Comment: SE = predict(fit,Modern_EarlyHolocene)$se

Comment: So is the standard error the same as the 95% confidence values which the statsmooth produces?

Comment: 1.96 * standard error gives you 95% confidence interval.